# Why is uWSGI using more memory than Apache?

Tags: django, nginx, uwsgi

I decided to try out NGINX/uWSGI for my Django application instead of Apache/mod_wsgi. My reason for giving this a try is that I heard NGINX/uWSGI uses less memory, performs better in high traffic situations, and NGINX is great for serving static content.

However I'm finding that uWSGI is using almost 5x more RAM than Apache.

```
ubuntu@domU-12-31-39-0A-9C-1A:~$ sudo ps_mem.py
 Private  +   Shared  =  RAM used       Program

184.0 KiB +  31.5 KiB = 215.5 KiB       atd
220.0 KiB +  94.0 KiB = 314.0 KiB       upstart-socket-bridge
260.0 KiB + 101.0 KiB = 361.0 KiB       upstart-udev-bridge
340.0 KiB +  63.0 KiB = 403.0 KiB       cron
392.0 KiB +  82.0 KiB = 474.0 KiB       sudo
560.0 KiB +  14.0 KiB = 574.0 KiB       dhclient3
612.0 KiB + 189.0 KiB = 801.0 KiB       getty (6)
816.0 KiB +  35.5 KiB = 851.5 KiB       dbus-daemon
660.0 KiB + 359.0 KiB =   1.0 MiB       udevd (3)
960.0 KiB +  74.0 KiB =   1.0 MiB       rsyslogd
  1.1 MiB +  38.5 KiB =   1.2 MiB       redis-server
  1.1 MiB + 146.5 KiB =   1.2 MiB       init
  1.7 MiB +   1.1 MiB =   2.9 MiB       nginx (3)
  1.3 MiB +   1.8 MiB =   3.1 MiB       sshd (3)
  7.5 MiB +  69.5 KiB =   7.6 MiB       bash
 14.4 MiB +   5.7 MiB =  20.1 MiB       apache2 (6)
 23.6 MiB + 113.0 KiB =  23.7 MiB       mysqld
 95.5 MiB +   8.6 MiB = 104.1 MiB       uwsgi (7)
---------------------------------
                        169.7 MiB
=================================
```

Is this expected?

Have I possibly configured something incorrectly? (master=true, 4 workers)

Do you only see the benefit when the server is under stress?

Comment: *"Do you only see the benefit when the server is under stress?"* I'd say it's a fair bet that you'll see a difference under some load, rather than just on startup.

Comment: It depends on the configuration. What is apache serving ? How much pre-forked processes does it have ? Does Apache pre-forks at all? I'm pretty sure uwsgi uses much less memory than apache. But without giving the actual configuration - you compare apples to peaches..

Comment: Apache is using pre-fork. 5 processes. So what I'm gathering is that this isn't unusual and nothing to worry about?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It all comes down to configuration. Because most of the memory comes from your fat Python web application, actual underlying WSGI server memory use generally contributes very little.

You should go watch my PyCon talk where I cover this specific issue and how people are deceived over the defaults the different WSGI server solutions use.

http://lanyrd.com/2012/pycon/spcdg/

In short, it is a bit of a mistruth that Apache/mod_wsgi will use a lot more memory. Configure it in a comparable way to other solutions and it would use comparable memory for same Python web application.

Comment: Thank you. I see how my question is too vague. The talk was helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Add next rules to project uWSGI .ini

[limit memory per process](http://projects.unbit.it/uwsgi/wiki/Doc#limit-as) in MB

```
limit-as=128
```

[max requests](http://projects.unbit.it/uwsgi/wiki/Doc#max-requests): recycle process when in reach 5k requests

```
max-requests=5000
```

Comment: Old answer but I'm curious on your opinion - won't your users get bad experience when your process will randomly restart because it reached max memory usage / max requests number?

Comment: @Greg0ry Worst case scenario (when user assume that something not ok) that process respawn and has to read sources from disk (not OS cache in RAM). And by "user assume" (on my projects) I mean that he get answer not in 50-200ms but in 500-2000 ms.